# What are sqlite development headers and how to install them?

Tags: python, header, pysqlite

I am trying to install pysqlite and have troubles with that. I found out that the most probable reason of that is missing sqlite headers and I have to install them.

However, I have no ideas what these headers are (where I can find them, what they are doing and how to install them).

Can anybody, pleas, help me with that?

Comment: Can you say what version of python you have and what platform you are on?

Comment: Right, we can't get much further without knowing platform specifics, including OS and CLI. (Linux & which specific linux distro? Windows, but which CLI?)

Comment: My platform: CentOS release 5.3 (Final).

Answer (score 19):

debian/ubuntu:

```
$ apt-get install libsqlite3-dev # or rpm -i sqlite-devel-something.rpm
```

---

I think a number of interpreters just recompile their small connection libraries on installation, but to do that they need the C .h files in addition to the library to link against. You may already have the library, because something else depended on it, but you don't necessarily have the `dev` package, which is kind of half-way between source and binary.

Part of it is straightforward, if you are going to develop with a library you need its interface headers.

But I think something more happened, at first, people tried all-source and all-binary distributions, but the all-binary ones were vulnerable to *dependency hell*, and the all-source ones were overkill. I think now that an interesting compromise is in use, a semi-source distribution where a program links to installed libraries by recompiling those parts of it that link to extension libraries. This makes a lot of sense with interpreters where most of the system can arrive in binary but the extension modules are dynamically loaded and compiled for the installed system. I think.

Comment: What platform are you on?  And which CLI?

Comment: My platform: CentOS release 5.3 (Final).
I have Python-2.6.2

Comment: Aha, so you need the `.rpm` instead of the `.deb` package. Your command will be something like `rpm -i sqlite3-devel-3.n.n.n.rpm`. CentOS doesn't seem to coordinate packages, so you need to go hunt down an rpm, and I guess you just have to know which RHEL corresonds to which CentOS. Start here, maybe: http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/sqlite/

Comment: For a person who dropped C++ for a decade or two and is just now picking it back up, the history lesson was very helpful!

Answer (score 8):

For me this worked (Redhat/CentOS):

$ sudo yum install sqlite-devel

Answer (score 0):

pysqlite needs to compiled/build before you can use it.  This requires C language header files (*.H) which come with the source code of sqllite itself.

i.e. sqllite and pysqlite are two different things.  Did you install sqlite prior to trying and build pysqllte ?  (or maybe you did, but did you do so just with the binaries;  you need the source package (or at least its headers) for pysqlite purposes.